# Waiting for interrupt-loop

Tags: c++

I need a code construction for my project which waits for some time, but when there is an interrupt (e.g. incoming udp packets) it leaves this loop, does something, and after this restart the waiting.
How can I implement this? My first idea is using `while(wait(2000))`, but wait is a void construct...
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I would put the loop inside a function

```
void awesomeFunction() {
    bool loop = true;

    while (loop) {
        wait(2000);
        ...
        ...
        if (conditionMet)
            loop = false;
    }
}
```

Then i would put this function inside another loop

```
while (programRunning) {
    awesomeFunction();

    /* Loop ended, do stuff... */
}
```

Comment: But then I always have to wait 2000 ms, and then my condition will be checked. If my condition is fullfilled for the time from 1000 to 1500 ms, your loop would never exit...

Comment: Well, reading your question again makes me think you'd benefit more by using a poll style of approach. I'm not certain what c++ provides in this matter, but c has a neat little function called select: http://manpages.courier-mta.org/htmlman2/select.2.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things I am not clear about from the question. Is this a multi-threaded application, where one thread handles (say) the UDP packets, and the other waits for the event, or is this single-threaded? You also didn't mention what operating system this is, which is relevant. So I am going to assume Linux, or something that supports the [poll](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) API, or something similar (like [select](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/select.2.html)).

Let's assume a single threaded application that waits for UDP packets. The main idea is that once you have the socket's file descriptor, you have an infinite loop on a call to `poll`. For instance:

```
#include <poll.h>
// ...
void handle_packets() {
  // m_fd was created with `socket` and `bind` or `connect`.
  struct pollfd pfd = {.fd = m_fd, .events = POLLIN};
  int timeout;
  timeout = -1; // Wait indefinitely
  // timeout = 2000; // Wait for 2 seconds
  while (true) {
    pfd.revents = 0;
    poll(&pfd, 1, timeout);
    if ((pfd.revents & POLLIN) != 0) {
      handle_single_packet();  // Method to actually read and handle the packet
    }
    if ((pfd.revents & (POLLERR | POLLHUP)) != 0) {
      break; // return on error or hangup
    }
  }
}
```

A simple example of `select` can be found [here](http://doolittle.icarus.com/ntpclient/).

---

If you are looking at a multi-threaded application, trying to communicate between the two threads, then there are several options. Two of which are:

1. Use the same mechanism above. The file descriptor is the result of a call to [pipe](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pipe.2.html). The thread sleeping gets the read end of the pipe. The thread waking get the write end, and writes a character when it's time to wake up.
2. Use C++'s `std::condition_variable`. It is documented [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), with a complete example. This solution depends on your context, e.g., whether you have a variable that you can wait on, or what has to be done.

Other interrupts can also be caught in this way. Signals, for instance, have a [signalfd](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/signalfd.2.html). Timer events have [timerfd](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/timerfd_create.2.html). This depends a lot on what you need, and in what environment you are running. For instance, `timerfd` is Linux-specific.